# converting Epoch timestamp to sql server(human readable format)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem in converting the Unix timestamp to sql server timestamp.

I have a data in excel sheet and I will import that data through a tool. So I am looking for a code or syntax which can convert that Epoch timestamp to sql server timestamp.

I have 3 different columns with the same format. How can I change the values in those columns.

For Example:

- Epoch timestamp ---1291388960
- sql server timestamp--- 2010-12-03 15:09:20.000

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> I have 3 different columns with the same format. How can I change the values in those columns.

To update 3 columns in a table, you can pair DATEADD seconds to the epoch (1 Jan 1970) with the column name, i.e.

```
update tbl set
    datetimecol1 = dateadd(s, epochcol1, '19700101'),
    datetimecol2 = dateadd(s, epochcol2, '19700101'),
    datetimecol3 = dateadd(s, epochcol3, '19700101')
```

You can't update in place since a bigint column cannot also be a datetime column.  You have to update them into 3 other columns.

Comment: there is problem here that wherein there epoch is in daylight time and when you convert you would lose one hour . not sure how to fix that .

Answer (score 32):

Use the [DATEADD function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819%28SQL.90%29.aspx):

```
SELECT DATEADD(ss, 1291388960, '19700101')
```

...specifying a date of January 1st, 1970.  In this example, it was provided in the YYYYMMDD format.

DATEADD will return a DATETIME data type, so if you have a table & column established -- you can use the function to INSERT/UPDATE depending on your needs.  Provide details, and I'll clarify.  Once you have a DATETIME to work with, you can use [CAST or CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819%28SQL.90%29.aspx) to format the date in TSQL.

Comment: thanks for giving me the syntax but i have about 20 million records.....how can I convert all those?

Comment: @Shahsra: Depends on what you want to do -- if this is temporary, use a temp table.  Otherwise, you need a column to dump the data into -- either by adding a column to the existing table, or a new table cloned from the original.  You have to provide details.

Comment: thanks a lot budyy... I got the solution I already did the changes. Really appreciate  for your help.