# Sql server convert date to 10 digit integer for comparison

Tags: sql-server-2000

I'm working with a database where dates are stored as 10 digit integers and where the user can query information within certain calendar date ranges. I was wondering what are the steps for converting a calendar date to a 10 digit integer for comparison with dates stored in a database.

I'm working with sql server 2000.

Comment: Can you give an example of one of these 10 digit integers? `yyyymmdd` is only 8 digits so what are the other two? Also why is it stored like that rather than using `datetime` anyway?

Comment: What algorithm is used to transform a date into a 10 digit integer?  Is there a specific start date that would equal 0?

Comment: Do you want to convert the dates in the query? I think it would be better to convert the dates before you query the DB... What language are you using for the application?

Comment: An example would be 1240494225 -> 2009-04-23-13:43:45.000 and I think the start date is January 1st,1970

Comment: possible duplicate of [converting Epoch timestamp to sql server(human readable format)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787827/converting-epoch-timestamp-to-sql-serverhuman-readable-format)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `SELECT DATEADD(second, 1240494225, '19700101')` to convert the number to a date and `SELECT DATEDIFF(second, '19700101', @some_date)` to go the other way.