# What date format is this? (001281379300724)

Tags: sql-server, datetime

Need to convert this timestamp (001281379300724) to YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss format in SQL Server, if possible. Any suggestions?

Comment: It would help if we knew roughly where you got the "timestamp" from, how that "timestamp" was created, etc...

Comment: It's most likely seconds since the UNIX epoch. In the example you linked that would be Mon, 09 Aug 2010 18:41:40 GMT.

Comment: Is it the number of milliseconds since 1971? UNIX time

Comment: That looks like a unix timestamp. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904256/how-can-i-convert-bigint-unix-timestamp-to-datetime-in-sql-server)

Comment: This is probably the UNIX seconds counter starting from Midnight of January 1, 1970. You can calculate from there the current timestamp

Comment: and this answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787827/converting-epoch-timestamp-to-sql-serverhuman-readable-format

Comment: @nightcracker Mind the number of digits. I think RyanGray might be right. 1281379300724 milliseconds would be Aug 2010, but 1281379300724 whole seconds would be over 40,000 years from now.

Comment: If this is not a value from a SQL timestamp column, do you at least have an example of known values and their corresponding dates in the format you want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This presumes the timestamp is ms since UNIX epoch. It only converts to the nearest second, but you could add ms to it(see below). It has to use two steps since dateadd requires an int. First add minutes by dividing by 60000, then add seconds.

```
DECLARE @yournum bigint
SET @yournum = 1281379300724     
SELECT DATEADD(ss, (@yournum / 1000)%60 , (DATEADD(mi, @yournum/1000/60, '19700101')))
```

Gives

```
 2010-08-09 18:41:40.000
```

To get ms precision: (yuck, probably a better way)

```
DECLARE @yournum bigint
SET @yournum = 1281379300724     
SELECT DATEADD(ms, (@yournum%1000),DATEADD(ss, (@yournum / 1000)%60 , (DATEADD(mi, @yournum/1000/60, '19700101'))))
```

Gives

```
2010-08-09 18:41:40.723
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is that if this is a SQL timestamp column (a.k.a [rowversion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)), you can't. Per the documentation for the type:

> Each database has a counter that is incremented for each insert or
>   update operation that is performed on a table that contains a
>   rowversion column within the database. This counter is the database
>   rowversion. This tracks a relative time within a database, not an
>   actual time that can be associated with a clock.

...

> The Transact-SQL timestamp data type is different from the timestamp
>   data type defined in the ISO standard.

Answer (score 1):

You can get slightly closer this way:

```
SELECT DATEADD(MINUTE, 1281379300724/1000/60, '19700101')
```

Result:

```
2010-08-09 18:41:00.000
```