# SQL Query to Select * From Table where date is between 7 days ago and now

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a simple query in SQL Server (2005 express). The purpose is to only choose data between now and 7 days ago. I cannot seem to get the GETDATE function to work in this example... Any ideas?

**PS - The date time in the column is in EPOCH so I believe the issue may be stemming from here with the datatype...

```
Select * From TB_Data
where TB_Data.nDate <= GETDATE()-7)
```

Comment: Try `>=` rather than `<=`.  And drop the final closing paren.

Comment: First, remove the last parenthesis. Second, you may as well try with `where nDate between GETDATE()-7 and GETDATE()`

Comment: `WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,[nDate],GETDATE()) <= 7`

Comment: @GordonLinoff That gives me "incorrect syntax near '7'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a parenthesis before the GETDATE() function will work.

```
Select * From TB_Data
where TB_Data.nDate <= (GETDATE() - 7)
```

With EPOCH, you will need to convert the date before comparing:

```
DATEADD(s, TB_Data.nDate, '19700101')
```

So the full query is:

```
Select * From TB_Data
where DATEADD(s, TB_Data.nDate, '19700101') <= (GETDATE() - 7)
```

Comment: I should also mention that the date time in the table is in EPOCH... My error now is failed when converting varchar value 'GetDATE() -7 to data type Int

Comment: Could you do something like: 
where DATEADD(s, TB_Data.nDate, '19700101') <= (GETDATE() - 7)
Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787827/converting-epoch-timestamp-to-sql-serverhuman-readable-format