# Get difference in minutes using epoch time in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am using automation tool in that I am getting now time in epoch format. There is no time. I am getting one is start of process time and other end process time

```
Process start time : 1505815205159
Process end time   : 1505816321742
```

I need the difference of these two epoch times in minutes in SQL Server - is there a way to do this?

Comment: may be this will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787827/converting-epoch-timestamp-to-sql-serverhuman-readable-format

Comment: just subtract one from another and divide by 60 to gives you minutes ! Why need `SQL Server` to do it ?

Comment: one from another you mean normal subtraction and then divide by 60 giving me 18000 minutes

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE :**

```
DECLARE @duration decimal (18,2)
SET @duration = 1505816321742 - 1505815205159
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(s, @duration * 1000, 0), 114)
```

**Result : 09:56:40:000**

**DateAdd Intervals :**

```
year, yyyy, yy = Year
quarter, qq, q = Quarter
month, mm, m = month
dayofyear = Day of the year
day, dy, y = Day
week, ww, wk = Week
weekday, dw, w = Weekday
hour, hh = hour
minute, mi, n = Minute
second, ss, s = Second
millisecond, ms = Millisecond
```

Comment: SELECT DATEADD(ss, 1291388960, '19700101') iam usinbg this its giving me arthematic  overflow error