# Convert int column with timestamp value into date format (Y-m-d)

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel-5

I have sql-server column called (date) with int type and the value for this column is timestamp like (1538254800) i need to select this column from my laravel sql query and appear it as date format (Y-m-d H:m:i pm) like (2018-09-29 09:00:00 pm)

Comment: That is [EPOCH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787827/converting-epoch-timestamp-to-sql-serverhuman-readable-format)... then you can use `CONVERT` to get it in the format you want.

Comment: `date(FORMAT, $string)` doesn't do it? or you want it done in SQL?

Comment: select CONVERT(datetime, convert(varchar(10), 20190329));

Answer (score 0):

### Casts

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#attribute-casting

Example:

```
class MyModel extends Model {
  // ...
  protected $casts = [
    'int_col_name' => 'datetime:u',
  ];
  // ...
}
```

---

### Date mutators

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

Example:

```
class MyModel extends Model {
  // ...
  protected $dates = [
    'int_col_name',
  ];
  // ...
}
```