# Convert column of type Float to Date in sql-server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, date, timestamp

My dates stored in a float column, I tried to change it to timestamp with no luck,
now I want to calculate the age from that field, I have tried all sorts of combinations using `CONVERT` and `CAST` functions, but it does not seem to work.

```
DoB
-434419200000
606960000000
1332806400000
1395878400000
-87350400000
890956800000
```

I tried:

```
 SELECT DATEADD(ss, dob, '19700101')
   from tbl

   //Result
   Error overflow .. arithmetique for type int, value= -434419200000.000000

    SELECT DATEADD(ss, CONVERT(bigint, dob, 101), '19700101')
    from tbl

    //Result
     Error while conversion from expression to type int.
```

**UPDATE**

*NOTE* that the data here is from milliseconds from the date"1970/1/1 00:00:00"

Thank you.

Comment: What "date" does `-434419200000` represent..? All your code does above it convert from the `float` value `-434419200000` to a `varchar` (of unspecified length). It doesn't do any kind of age calculations.

Comment: It represent a date of birth in timestamp, but the column is of type float, age calculation is further step after I get the data as date.

Comment: How did you get that value? If we don't know what date an apparently arbitrary number represents, we cannot help you.

Comment: You'll have to figure out who or what is storing these values and what they mean. This approach to time stamps is not native to SQL Server; you can't get a negative number out of a date with any of the built-in types. It could be, for example, that `-434419200000` is a Unix date/time value in milliseconds, starting from 1970-01-01, so it would represent a DOB of 1956-03-27, but that's pure speculation without seeing the actual processed value. If it *is* a Unix timestamp, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2904256/4137916).

Comment: *" age calculation is further step after I get the data as date."* hence why I ask, what date is `-434419200000`? If *you* don't know that, how can you ever hope to work out what someone's DOB is, let alone us?

Comment: It represent milliseconds from a specific date see the update, sorry that I thought  it was a timestamp.

Comment: So it is an epoch date.

Comment: Do these answer your question? [converting Epoch timestamp to sql server(human readable format)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4787827/2029983) followed by [How to calculate age (in years) based on Date of Birth and getDate()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1572110/2029983)

Comment: @Larnu Yes, thanks, but non of them helps!

Comment: Really, @TiyebM ? The first question clearly shows you hiow to convert an epoch to a date, and the latter how to calculate age. how do they *not*?

Comment: @Larnu In the first one I tried `SELECT DATEADD(ss, dob, '19700101')
from tbl`, it gives exception of incompatibity of int value `-434419200000.000000`, I tried to convert the float value to int, then I went through `Error while convert expression to int type`, I think the problem is related to the float data type of column.

Comment: `-434419200000` is too small for an int, you need to use a `bigint`.

Comment: The problem is not `float` but the fact that `DATEADD` doesn't support anything but `INT` and there's no `DATEADD_BIG`. `SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, CONVERT(BIGINT, -434419200000) / 1000, '19700101')`.

Comment: Finally an answer, thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mention in the comments, this is a combined duplicate of the questions [converting Epoch timestamp to sql server(human readable format)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4787827/2029983) and [How to calculate age (in years) based on Date of Birth and getDate()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1572110/2029983).

Sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (DoB float);
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (DoB)
VALUES (-434419200000),
       (606960000000),
       (1332806400000),
       (1395878400000),
       (-87350400000),
       (890956800000);
```

Then using the first link we get:

```
SELECT DATEADD(SECOND, DoB / 1000,'19700101') --As yours is milliseconds, not seconds.
FROM dbo.YourTable;
```

Then we can use the answer from the second link:

```
SELECT YT.DoB,
       V.DateOfBirth,
       CONVERT(int,DATEDIFF(yy, V.DateOfBirth, GETDATE()) + 
       CASE WHEN GETDATE() >= DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(yyyy, GETDATE()), DATEPART(m, V.DateOfBirth), DATEPART(d, V.DateOfBirth)) THEN (1.0 * DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(yyyy, GETDATE()), DATEPART(m, V.DateOfBirth), DATEPART(d, V.DateOfBirth)), GETDATE()) / DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(yyyy, GETDATE()), 1, 1), DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(yyyy, GETDATE()) + 1, 1, 1)))
            ELSE -1 * (-1.0 * DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(yyyy, GETDATE()), DATEPART(m, V.DateOfBirth), DATEPART(d, V.DateOfBirth)), GETDATE()) / DATEDIFF(DAY, DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(yyyy, GETDATE()), 1, 1), DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(yyyy, GETDATE()) + 1, 1, 1)))
       END) AS Age
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES (DATEADD(SECOND, YT.DoB / 1000, '19700101'))) V (DateOfBirth);
```

If this answer helps, I suggest upvoting the answers that I link above as well, as this is a combination of those said answers.

Comment: Right, thank you, I missed the division by 1000 mentioned by @SalmanA .

Answer (score 1):

The correct datatype would be `bigint` instead of float. In fact I would rather import the timestamps in a `date` column.

Having said that, divide the number by 1000 to avoid overflow error:

```sql
select dateadd(second, -434419200000e0 / 1000, '1970-01-01')
-- 1956-03-27 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Thank you very much, now it works despite of the data type of column, could you please develop this to get the age from now, thank you